# Problems while hosting the code in github

Tags: git, github-pages

Here is my git repo for time tracking: [Click here!!](https://github.com/akulkarni9/TimeTracker)
I wanted to host that project in git pages. So I followed these steps:

> 1. Create a repo with the name, username.github.io. I created a new repo akulkarni9.github.com.
> 2. Open the repository's page on GitHub.
> 3. In your repository's right sidebar, click settings.
> 4. Click the Automatic Page Generator button and author my content in markup editor.
> 5. Click the Continue To Layouts button
> 6. Preview your content in our themes.
> 7. When you find a theme that you like, click Publish page.

I did exact things as mentioned in those steps. When I opened `akulkarni.github.io` in a browser, that project wasn't hosted.
Then I executed the following commands:

```
cd to repository in local system  
git fetch origin
```

Output was:

```
remote: Counting objects: 56, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (56/56), done.
From https://github.com/akulkarni9/akulkarni9.github.io
   7ac8179..651c795  master     -> origin/master
```

Then I executed this command:

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

And I got an error:

```
error: pathspec 'gh-pages' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your repository only has a `master` branch, it doesn't have a `gh-pages` branch. That's what the error says.

If you want to create that branch locally, you should do the following:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
```

Instead of this:

```
git checkout gh-pages
```

Or, as the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/) suggests:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

Which will create the branch without any parents.

**Update**

Now that you've set up the `gh-pages` branch locally, you'll need to add content to it and push the branch to your remote repository. You can do that as follows (taken from the documentation):

```
echo "My Page" > index.html
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

If you've done the above. You will have an `index.html` file with `My Page` as its content. Just edit that file (to what ever you want it to be) and push your changes:

```
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "Updated the index.html file."
git push origin gh-pages
```

That should do it. Also, take note of one of the last lines of the documentation:

> After your push to the `gh-pages` branch, your Project Pages site will be available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`

**Update, Part II**

If you're still having problems after all of this, there is an option to create Project Pages [with the automatic generator](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/).

**Update, Part III**

Ok, so instead of creating `gh-pages` branch in your Github site, create that branch in the repository you want to show as a Project Page.

So, let's say you want your [Time Tracker](https://github.com/akulkarni9/TimeTracker) project as a Project Page:

1. Create a `gh-pages` branch in your TimeTracker project (as you've previously done in your `*.github.io` repository).
2. Add your content.
3. Push it to Github.
4. Now visit: https://akulkarni9.github.io/TimeTracker

Comment: yeah, done it... thank you. But when I open akulkarni9.github.io in browser, then that code isn't hosted. How can I fix it?

Comment: @QWERTYking I've updated my answer. Basically you'll have to add your content now and push it to github.

Comment: You mean that I should add my code to `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: @QWERTYking Yes, see the **Update** part of my answer. If you'll just execute the first part of that (creating an index.html, adding it to git, committing it and pushing it to the remote `gh-pages` branch), you'll see that page on your Project Page.

Comment: Okay, I did that, I pushed my code to gh-pages branch as you told. When I go to https://akulkarni9.github.io/gh-pages, then I got 404 error.

Comment: @QWERTYking Ok, I just realised what went wrong here. Check out **Update, Part III** in my answer. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do when you get the message
*error: pathspec 'gh-pages' did not match any file(s) known to git.*

From Git Bash:

```
git branch -a  (show all branches, local and remote).
```

If your branch *branch-name* does not appear on the list under local or remote it means *branch-name* does not exist locally or on your remote repository.
Create it locally w/ `git checkout -b branch-name`

If the desired branch is found remote, you can check it out w/

```
git checkout -b branch-name origin/branch-name
```

[Good source for Git documentation.](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/doc)
[Git cheat sheet for quick reference.](https://training.github.com/kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf)

Also, you created the repo *akulkarni9.github.com* when the .com subdomain is deprecated by GitHub Pages.  You should try recreating the repo as *akulkarni9.github.io* instead.

Comment: I know he said that he created the `*.github.com` repo in his question, but he actually didn't. He did create the `*.github.io` version. [Here](https://github.com/akulkarni9/akulkarni9.github.io) it is ;).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you completed the final step & hit the "Publish page" button?

When you hit this button, GitHub will create a new branch into which it commits the settings & code behind your project page. Once your page is created, you'll be able to see it listed in the branch selector on your main project page.

For example, if you look at my [Magic8Ball project](https://github.com/bitcrazed/Magic8Ball), you'll be able to find the [gh-pages branch](https://github.com/bitcrazed/magic8ball/tree/gh-pages) for the project's [GitHub page](http://bitcrazed.github.io/Magic8Ball/).

Once you have the branch configured in GitHub, pull the project you cloned previously and you'll be able to see the new gh-pages branch arrive:

```
> git pull
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 7
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From github.com:bitcrazed/Magic8Ball
 * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
Already up-to-date.
```

You'll now be able to checkout the new `gh-pages` branch:

```
> git checkout -t origin/gh-pages
Branch gh-pages set up to track remote branch gh-pages from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'gh-pages'
```

HTH.